# How to structure ML Vision OCR results into table format?

Tags: android, ocr, image-recognition, mlvision

I am using [Firebase ML Vision](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/recognize-text) to recognize text from images. I am getting pretty decent output. For [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG9Ni.jpg) image, [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7z0h.png) is the output. I want to structure this output in a table format, like it is displayed in the image, there are things like bounding box, rect. But I am not sure how to do that. Can someone help me to achieve this?

Comment: ML vision return only what you have put it. for table format you have to create view and maintain string return by ML vision.

Comment: Yeah but like how do i identify which specific value belongs to which one, as in this result it has given numeric values after two values, so how can we actually differentiate as there would be a different image every time.

Comment: compare with last one image data. well you can't get accurate value every time even capture same image.